# Sumir com texto em CSS

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra fazer um span aparecer só quando estiver na versão mobile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem, eu gostaria que o texto "Sair", aparecesse só quando mudasse para versão mobile.
Tem como?

Comment: `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score -3):

Eu faria assim, se vc começou a desenvolver com first mobile ou seja começou a desenvolver para celular primeiro vc usa (min width) ou se começou pelo pc usa max
@media screen and (max width: 600px){
 span: display:none;
}